# How to restrict a value taken in select statement by function

Tags: function, plsql, restriction

I have a query like this

```
select *,  SomeFunction(input=> value) as SomeName
from SomeTable
```

I want to put a  restriction like bellow

```
select *,  SomeFunction(input=> value) as SomeName
from SomeTable
where SomeName != 'this value'
```

But its giving me bellow error.

```
 ORA-00904: "SomeName ": invalid identifier
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(select *,  SomeFunction(input=> value) as SomeName
from SomeTable)a
where A.SomeName != 'this value'
```